# MUI DataGrid - Automatically hide filter menu on enter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Is there a way to hide the filtering menu when pressing enter with MUI DataGrid ?
Until now, we are obliged to click somewhere else to hide it.

I'm talking about this :

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding an onKeyDown prop to the filterPanel section of the component props

```
const apiRef = useGridApiRef()   

return(
    <DataGrid
        apiRef={apiRef}
        rows={rowsData}
        columns={myColumns}
        componentProps={{
            filterPanel: {
                onKeyDown: (event) => {
                    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
                        apiRef.current.hideFilterPanel()
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    />
)
```